# How to retrieve date from database & bind it to datechooser?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ado.net

I am using SQL server 2005,I want to retrieve date stored in database for particular record & want to set that date to datechooser. How can i do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What database framework are you using (ADO.NET, LINQ to SQL, EF, ...) ? What GUI framework are you using (WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, ...)?

Comment: Where does your DateChooser come from? What UI framework, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

```
using (SqlConnection connection= new SqlConnection("CONNECTIONSTRING");
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT-QUERY", connection))
{
    //set parameters if you need them
    //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramName", paramValue);

    connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    if(reader.Read())
    {
         object date = reader["COLUMNNAME"];
         //Do something with the date...
    }
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't be the complete solution. Just a hint to the way to do it.   Ok i've forgot to open the connection... sorry ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker dateTimePicker1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker();            
dateTimePicker1.Name = "dateTimePicker1";
dateTimePicker1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 20);            

SqlConnection connection= new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DATASOURCE;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD"); 
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Top 1 colDate From tblTemp", connection)) 
{     
    connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();     
    if (reader.Read())     
    {          
        DateTime dt=new DateTime();
        dt=DateTime.Now;
        bool b=DateTime.TryParse(reader["CreatedAt"].ToString(),out dt);
        dateTimePicker1.Value = dt;
    }

    connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
mytextbox.Text = Result_returned_from_Execute_Scalar();
```